# apache and tomcat get remote ip

Tags: java, apache, tomcat7

I have this setting in my apache, this work fine, but in my app when a get remote address this return local IP (127.0.0.1), how I solve this problem?

```
</Location>        
</VirtualHost><VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName yourapp.yourdomain.com
ServerAlias yourapp.*        
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On     
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>     
ProxyPass /webapp http://localhost:8080/webapp
ProxyPassReverse /webapp http://localhost:8080/webapp    
<Location /webapp>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Location>        
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You'll need to use the `X-Forwarded-For` header on the request. Apache should add this header during the proxy

Comment: where do I use this? do you have an example? thanks you!

Comment: thanks you @ColinMorelli I found `request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For")`

Comment: Be careful if you use that, you may not get the IP you search for (in case there is multiple X-Forwarded-For header). Better to use Arun P Johnny answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Remote_IP_Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_IP_Valve) to set the actual IP address in the request.

In your tomcat/conf/server.xml add the valve like

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
   remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for"
/>
```